# Windows Phone 7 Add PivotItem to Pivot with code in real time, how?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can I add Pivot Items in runtime, and add some content to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create PivotItems at runtime just like you would create any UIelement. For example like this:

```
PivotItem pitem = new PivotItem(); //create pivotitem                
pitem.Content =  //set pivotitem content
MyPivot.Items.Add(pitem);//Add pivotitem to your pivot
```